# Java RSA encryption faild

Tags: java, security, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am trying to encrypt some data using a string public key 
and its failing with the error : *java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format*

my code is:

```
public class Encryptor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pk = "<here goes my public key>";
        String data = encryptData("Israel", pk);
        System.out.println(data);
    }

    public static String encryptData(String rawData, String publicKey){
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Start of encryptData with data length:" + rawData.length());
            System.out.println("Public Key: " + publicKey);
            X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKey.getBytes());
            KeyFactory factory= KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWITHSHA-256ANDMGF1PADDING");
            RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)factory.generatePublic(spec);        
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
            byte[] encryptedByteData =  cipher.doFinal(rawData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            encryptedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedByteData);
            encryptedString = encryptedString.replaceAll("\\s", "");
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in encryptData." + e);
        }finally{
            System.out.println("End of encryptData with result length:" + (encryptedString==null?"null":encryptedString.length()));
        }
        return encryptedString;  
    }     
}
```

Can some one help with this?

Comment: Please include the public key string. This is an encoding issue; `X509EncodedKeySpec` expects DER encoding, which is a binary encoding. This encoding is not directly compatible with strings.

Comment: I extracted the public key from a given .cer file and I got something like: ---- Begin public key ---- . . . . . . ---- end public key-----

Comment: The binary DER encoding is what you get when you decode the base 64 in the middle of the PEM encoded string that you have. Try to decode and input the result. Bouncy Castle has utility classes to handle PEM.